# How to visit a website for an article, in new tab, from Feedly, with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, feedly

I view "headlines" only in Feedly.  The hotkeys <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> work fine for iterating through the list.  Without using the mouse, how can I open a new tab for the headline link?  The [hotkeys](https://blog.feedly.com/feedly-keyboard-shortcuts/) per Feedly:

[image: hotkeys]

Once an article is selected, how do visit the website?  Press <kbd>c</kbd>?  Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, pressing `?` gives me a different list, where `v` will open a new tab and switch focus to the new tab.

Would be nice to ***not*** switch focus to the new tab, but, eh, works kinda sorta.